# Appium crosswalk- cordova application

Tags: appium

I'd like to run Appium tests on a Crosswalk-Cordova application using cucumber with appium 1.3.5 version.But i am not able to switch to WEBVIEW context. Its returning only NATIVE_APP context. So I could not run the test.Can any one tell me, appium support Cross walk ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a different web driver than appium. This is the official web driver for selenium based testing:

https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Crosswalk-WebDriver

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that was created regarding crosswalk apps. 
There is a issue on Appium on this. https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4597#issuecomment-197307227
I'm not sure if this will work with Appium version 1.3.5, but I have tested currently it on Appium 1.4.16. On windows I used this solution and it worked for me.

You have to use a modified Chromedriver that gives access to the crosswalk webview. You can try to build it yourself, or just use a prebuilt chromedriver.

Note: with Appium 1.5 this won't, because android-hybrid.js isn't there anymore.

https://github.com/ITKarel/ChromeDriver

Answer (score 0):

For the getting webview in hybrid app .apk file must be in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

the new appium update already support crosswalk but the driver still not , this is why you still have problems . you can download this driver and just switch it in your appium files under appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win. 
also you will need the latest appium update (from last week)
download the driver from here : 
https://github.com/piotrekkmt/chromedriver-appium